# Make supervisord log to file and stdout

Tags: docker, supervisord

I have a docker container running a ping command. This process is managed by supervisord and this is my config file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:ping]
command=ping 1.1.1.1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/ping.out.log
```

The `stdout` of `ping 1.1.1.1` is being saved to `/var/log/ping.out.log`

**I'd also like it to be sent to `/dev/stdout` so I can view the log in my console.**

My hacky way to do this is run a second process to `tail -f` the log file. So my hacky config file looks like this:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:ping]
command=ping 1.1.1.1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/ping.out.log

[program:ping-log]
command=tail -f /var/log/ping.out.log
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
redirect_stderr=true
```

**Question is, is this 'hacky' approach ok? Or is there a better way to do this?**
I want to be able to run `docker log <container id>` to get my logs

Comment: Check this comment, probably could give you some ideas: https://github.com/immortal/immortal/issues/34#issuecomment-361555918

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me but according to someone else's suggestion, I can use `tee` if I used immortal instead of supervisord. Might switch to that